# My "bolding" function builds up strings in a weird way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Based on a function I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57597666/9774624) I am trying to build a component that highlights every word from an array I'll provide, inside the string I give it.

For example, if I'll use it like this:

```
  <Highlight
    body="Hi there stack overflow, hope you're all well"
    items={["there", "hope"]}
  />
```

What I'd like to get back is:

Hi **there** stack overflow, **hope** you're all well

So sometimes it works, and other times it doesn't, and I can't figure out the pattern.

Using the example string, if I'll give it this array `["there"]` then I'll get it correctly printing:

Hi **there** stack overflow, hope you're all well

If I'll give it this array `["there", "hope"]` then I'll get it correctly printing:

Hi **there** stack overflow, **hope** you're all well

BUT if I'll give it this array `["there", "hope", "overflow"]` then I'll get this weird string:

Hi **there** stack overflow, **hopeoverflowoverflowo**verflow, hope you're all well

This is my function currently:

```
const highlightWords = (source, target, callback) => {
  if (!source) return res;
  if (!target) return source;

  const defaultHighlight = s => <em key={Math.random(1000)}>{s}</em>;
  const res = [source];

  let lastOffset = 0;

  target.forEach(element => {
    res.forEach(stringEl => {
        console.log(typeof stringEl)
      if (typeof stringEl === typeof "")
        // Uses replace callback, but not its return value
        stringEl.replace(new RegExp(element, "gi"), (val, offset) => {
          // Push both the last part of the string, and the new part with the highlight
          res.push(
            stringEl.substr(lastOffset, offset - lastOffset),
            // Replace the string with JSX or anything.
            (callback || defaultHighlight)(val)
          );
          lastOffset = offset + val.length;
        });
    });
  });

  // Push the last non-highlighted string
  res.push(source.substr(lastOffset));
  res.shift();
  return res;
};
```

And this is my component:

```
export const Highlight = ({ body, items}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {highlightWords(body, items, s => (
        <span className="bold-700" key={Math.random(1000)}>
          {s}
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Just a guess, but you are modifying the `res` while working on it and the overflow word comes before hope in input body, that might be messing up. What happens if you give array `["there", "overflow", "hope"]` array as the items? Does it still mess up the result?

Comment: @Sunil Yes that it! I've resorted to using an external package that provides me more stuff than I care building at this point, but you're spot on. As soon as I give it the words in the right order everything works right. Submit it as an answer and I'll approve it.