# How can I compare two strings and replace matching words with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, loops, string-comparison

I am trying to create a function which takes in 2 strings:

-
title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",

-
itle_highlighted: "ipsum amet",

and returns one string or array containing the all words in `title` in addition words defined in the string `title_highlighted` will have a certain property and replace their matching word in `title`.

End result should be something like: `<h1>Lorem<span style={{color: "orange"}}>impsum</span>dolor sit<span style={{color: "orange"}}>amet</span>/h1>`

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Y5q.png)

My approach so far:

```
const highlightHeading = (title, title_highlighted) => {
  const title_arr = title.trim().split(/\s+/);
  const title_highlighted_arr = title_highlighted.trim().split(/\s+/);

  for (const element1 of title_arr) {
    console.log(element1);
    for (const element2 of title_highlighted_arr) {
      if (element1 === element2) {
        const highlighted = `<span style={{ color: "orange" }}>${element1}</span>`;
        console.log(highlighted);
      }
    }
  }
};
highlightHeading("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "ipsum amet");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the result to be JSX elements or strings?

Comment: Preferably the end result should be JSX elements. Asked for strings to keep it more general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to highlight matches within a string with JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597563/how-to-highlight-matches-within-a-string-with-jsx)

Comment: @Emile Bergeron Mr. Polywhirl gave me an answer which perfectly fits my needs, despite my question not being too specific. But your link will be helpful nonetheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `<HighlightedHeading>` component that accepts a `color`, `title`, and `words`.

```js
const { useMemo, useState } = React;

const tokenize = (str, delim = /\s+/) => str.trim().split(delim);

const toWordArray = (words) => {
  if (Array.isArray(words)) return words;
  if (typeof words === 'string') return tokenize(words);
  return []; // or throw Error
};

const toWordSet = (words) =>
  new Set(toWordArray(words).map(word => word.toLowerCase()));

const HighlightedHeading = (props) => {
  const { color, title, words } = props;
  const wordSet = useMemo(() => toWordSet(words), [words]);
  return (
    <h2 className="highlighted-text">
      {tokenize(title).map((token) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          {wordSet.has(token)
            ? <span style={{ color }}>{token}</span>
            : token}
          {/* Add spaces for copy-paste */}
          {' '}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </h2>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <HighlightedHeading
        color="yellow"
        title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        words="ipsum amet"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
    .render(<App title="Example using Hooks:" />);
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, #root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #222;
  color: #FFF;
}

.highlighted-text {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5ch; /* Display spaces in HTML */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! Thanks for providing a component. Will take my time to understand your approach.

Answer (score -1):

The naive splitting approach doesn't take punctuation into account (e.g. `Lorem ipsum? Dolor amet!`). You can try a regex with a word boundary `\b` instead:

```js
title = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

keywords = ["ipsum", "amet"]

regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + keywords.join('|') + ')\\b', 'g')

result = title.replace(regex, '<span whatever>$&</span>')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Much better approach.